Find the domain and range of $y = \dfrac{x}{2-3x}$. Why don't we need to check if $x(y) \notin \text{Dom}(y)$?
Find the domain and range of $y = \dfrac{x}{2-3x}$.
Clearly, $\text{Dom}(y) = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{\dfrac23\}.$
To find the range, I find $x(y) = \dfrac{2y}{1+3y}$. It's clear that $x$ is defined for $y \neq -\dfrac{1}{3}$. I initially also checked if $x(y) \neq \dfrac23$. This turns out to be true, and it seems this check is unnecessary. I wondered if that's true and if it is indeed unnecessary, why?
To elaborate on my confusion, $y = \dfrac{x}{2-3x}\iff\begin{cases}x\neq \frac23\\x=\frac{2y}{1+3y}\end{cases}$. It seems the two conditions are independent of each other. Why an extraction of $y$ from the second condition doesn't need to be verified with the first condition?
Thank you!

In the original equation ($y=\frac{x}{2-3x}$), when we say $x\neq(2/3)$ it means that $y$ is not defined when $x$ is equal to $2/3$. It also holds for the last equation $x=(2y)/(1+3y)$.

@User Hi, thank you. How about this function, $y = \frac{x^2}{x(x-1)}$ ? Clearly, the domain is $\mathbb{R}\setminus{0,1}$ and $x = \frac{y}{y-1}$. In this example, if we only checked for values of $y$ that make $x$ defined, then the range would be $\mathbb{R}\setminus{1}$. However, if we checked against the conditions for $x$, namely $x \neq 0$, it turns out that $y \neq 0$ too. The check with the domain seems necessary in this case, but I wondered what makes this example different from the original one.

"I wondered what makes this example different from the original one" $y=\frac{x^2}{x(x-1)}$ is not the same as $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$. It is $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$ and $x\not=0$. It follows from $x\not=0$ that $y\not=0$.
